# .NET Core View not updating after deploying in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

As above-mentioned, I am having an issue on the server side which I could not see the updates I made.
I believe I already did all the possible resolution found in the internet to fix the issue and asked some of my colleagues yet nothing seems to work.

My app is working fine on my Local, I also see the changes I made in the interface after running commands ("npm run build-watch") on my git bash terminal.

Comment: If you restart your site on IIS after you did a new deployment, does it work well?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I already found the problem. I did not include the folders like (wwwroot, zh-TW etc.)